# how to check the type of data returned from PHP in jQuery post method

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, type-conversion

**Type of data**

```
[{"id":"1","value":"Google"},{"id":"2","value":"Samsung"}]
```

Now I have a general function that performs certain actions based on the type of data being returned.

for this particular data I am checking if it is array or not. 
In order to check the type of the data being return I am using the following custom function.

```
function typeOf (obj) {
  return {}.toString.call(obj).split(' ')[1].slice(0, -1).toLowerCase();
}
```

now if I call `typeOf(1)` it returns "number" as answer

if I call `typeOf("foo")` it return "string" as answer

**The Problem**

calling `typeOf(data)` where `data = [{"id":"1","value":"Google"},{"id":"2","value":"Samsung"}]` being echoed from php page it gives "string" as answer

It only returns array if the recieved array type data variable is passed through following function as

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Now, I understand it might be the case that what ever gets echoed from php comes in string form but isn't there any way it can be changed as my php page is doing following

```
echo json_encode(array(array(some_key=>some_data)));
```

Comment: Call `header('Content-Type: application/json');` in your PHP file before echoing the JSON.

Comment: @DJDavid98 write that as answer so I can accept it. and why negative votes. What was wrong with the post?

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto didn't my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jQuery to know that you're sending JSON data, the server has to respond with the correct `Content-Type` header. In PHP, this can easily be achieved by calling `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before any output, and jQuery will attempt to parse the response.

This will result in the `data` parameter of your success handler to be an object containing the values from the JSON. Make sure to check that you get an `object` type data variable, because any other type should indicate that malformed JSON data is coming from your server.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/endpoint.php',
    method: "POST",
    data: {key:'value'},
    success: function(data){
        if (typeof data !== 'object')
            return console.error('Invalid data', data);

        // Do something with the response
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the value you get as a result of AJAX call, from PHP or JSP, will return it as String. You need to parse the string to make the script to understand the datatype correctly. You can do something like this:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);

if (typeof data == "object") {
  // JSON Data
} else {
  // String Data
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
```

```html
<script>
  function parseData(data) {
    if (data.length > 0)
      data = JSON.parse(data);
    if (typeof data == "object")
      return "This is JSON with keys.";
    else
      return "This is a String of " + data.length + " characters.";
  }
</script>
<p><strong>JSON Object</strong></p>
<p><script>document.write(parseData('{"a": "Alphabet", "b": "Fun"}'));</script></p>
<p><strong>String / Number</strong></p>
<p><script>document.write(parseData(''));</script></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're getting that data via ajax. Have you specified `dataType: 'json'` in the ajax function? If no dataType is specified, jQuery will guess, and sometimes, it guesses wrong.

(**Edit:** More on the `$.ajax` function here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ )